# When to use CDbl and CStr functions using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, string, double

I'm learning to use this program. I'm a few weeks into learning it, and I'm understanding most of it fine, but I just cannot get a grasp on when to use the `CDbl`, `CInt`, `CStr`, etc. functions. Here's an example of a few lines of code I can't get a grasp of:

```
If IsNumeric(txtFirst.Text) And IsNumeric(txtSecond.Text) Then
  txtSum.Text = CStr(CDbl(txtFirst.Text) + CDbl(txtSecond.Text))
```

This program is supposed to take two numbers that are input by the user and add them together. Simple. I was playing around with it, and I took out the `CDbl` and `CStr` functions, and the two numbers that were supposed to be added together were only added side by side (for example, if I input 2 and 15 as my numbers it would spit out 215).

So I'm curious when to use these functions.

How come on the second line, it says `CStr(CDbl(`? Why would I need to convert to double, THEN to string? Which is my understanding, unless I am reading this wrong.

Another question I have is, if I declare `var1` as `Dim var1 as Double`. I constantly see the next line as `var1 = CDbl(txtbox.text)` and so on. I don't understand why we need to convert to Double here, since when I declared the variable as a double, it should already be in a double form already, shouldn't it?

Comment: In VB, CDbl, CStr, etc are **operators**, not functions. Most of the time the distinction doesn't matter, but it can change the semantics now and then.

Answer (score 5):

1. The inner `CDbl(txtFirst.Text)` converts the first textbox's value to a number.  The outer `CStr(... + ...)` converts the whole sum back to a string.
2. Your variable is declared as a `Double`, but the `Text` property is a `String`.
   You need `CDbl` to convert the string to a number so that it can fit inside the variable.

Comment: It may help him to know that '+' concatenates strings, which is why he is essing 215 instead of 17 in one scenario.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this code:

```
 txtSum.Text = CStr(CDbl(txtFirst.Text) + CDbl(txtSecond.Text))
```

Let's separate it into pieces. First of all, value in a textbox control is of String type. In order to perform ADDITION, the string type needs to be converted into double type, so you do `CDbl(txtFirst.Text)` and `CDbl(txtSecond.Text)`

The ADDITION operation is done by `CDbl(txtFirst.Text) + CDbl(txtSecond.Text)`. In order to assign the result of that ADDITION to a textbox control, you need to convert it to String type. So you do `CStr()` on `CDbl(txtFirst.Text) + CDbl(txtSecond.Text)`. So the full operation in one line code is `txtSum.Text = CStr(CDbl(txtFirst.Text) + CDbl(txtSecond.Text))`